# Output data is not storing in output declared variable in powershell script

Tags: powershell

Output data is not storing in output declared variable in powershell script

Here output variable declined as $results

Script

```
function find {

  #$outputBox.Clear()

  $Results = Import-Csv -Path "D:\Excel\Data\List.csv" -Header "EventID", "TimeCreated", "Computer", "TargetUserName", "SubjectUserName", "HOSTName", "Filename" | Where-Object {$_.TargetUserName -eq $inputBoxgmr} | Select-Object "TimeCreated", "TargetUserName","HOSTName" | Out-String
  
  $Results | convertto-json
  
  # Assign Result to OutputBox
  $outputBox.Text = "$Results"

  # Clear OutputBox
  $inputBoxgmr.Clear()
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You've got a few different issues in your script - you probably don't want ```| out-string``` after your ```| select-object```, and you probably mean ```$Results = $Results | converto-json```, but just to clarify, can you give an example of what you're expecting ```$outputBox.text``` to contain?

Comment: I want display these results in outbox of powershell forms in table format. Kindly help me I am new for shell scripting @mclayton

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text - cut and paste the text instead and use code fences to format it. Have a read of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3156906 for more info.

Comment: Try ```$outputBox.Text = ($Results | format-list | out-string)```, but remove ```| out-string``` from after your ```select-object``` first...

Comment: Okay kindly see the i had uploaded the output in my original post @mclayton